# Create index on two unrelated table in Solr

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene

I want to create index between two tables, stock and auction. Basically I am working on a product site. So I have to create index on both tables. and they are not related at all.

In data-config.xml, that I created to create index, I wrote the following code

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database" user="root" password=""/>
    <document name="content">
        <entity name="stock" query="select ST_StockID,ST_StockCode,ST_Name,ST_ItemDetail from stock where estatus = 'Active' limit 100">
            <field column="ST_StockID" name="stock_ST_StockID" />
            <field column="ST_StockCode" name="stock_ST_StockCode" />
            <field column="ST_Name" name="stock_ST_Name" />
            <field column="ST_ItemDetail" name="stock_ST_ItemDetail" />
        <entity name="auction" query="select iauctionid,rad_number,vsku,auction_code from auction limit 100">
            <field column="iauctionid" name="auction_iauctionid" />
            <field column="rad_number" name="auction_rad_number" />
            <field column="vsku" name="auction_vsku" />
            <field column="auction_code" name="auction_auction_code" />
        </entity>
        </entity>

    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

and the schema.xml contains the fields are given below.

```
 <field name="stock_ST_StockID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="stock_ST_StockCode" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="stock_ST_Name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="stock_ST_ItemDetail" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

    <field name="auction_iauctionid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="auction_rad_number" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="auction_vsku" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="auction_auction_code" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

But this way the indexes are being created in wrong way as I put the other table data into the first table in data-config.xml. If I create two entity element like given below then the indexes are not being created.

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lc" user="root" password=""/>
    <document name="content">
        <entity name="stock" query="select ST_StockID,ST_StockCode,ST_Name,ST_ItemDetail from stock where estatus = 'Active' limit 100">
            <field column="ST_StockID" name="stock_ST_StockID" />
            <field column="ST_StockCode" name="stock_ST_StockCode" />
            <field column="ST_Name" name="stock_ST_Name" />
            <field column="ST_ItemDetail" name="stock_ST_ItemDetail" />

        </entity>
        <entity name="auction" query="select iauctionid,rad_number,vsku,auction_code from auction limit 100">
            <field column="iauctionid" name="auction_iauctionid" />
            <field column="rad_number" name="auction_rad_number" />
            <field column="vsku" name="auction_vsku" />
            <field column="auction_code" name="auction_auction_code" />
        </entity>
    </document>
  </dataConfig>
```

I did not get your answer, can you pls elaborate a little more. I also have the same requirement. I have two tables stock and auction. Basically I am working on a product site. So I have to create index on both tables. and they are not related at all.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors when indexing the data ??

The following data config is fine as you have two unrelated items.

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lc" user="root" password=""/>
    <document name="content">
        <entity name="stock" query="select ST_StockID,ST_StockCode,ST_Name,ST_ItemDetail from stock where estatus = 'Active' limit 100">
            <field column="ST_StockID" name="stock_ST_StockID" />
            <field column="ST_StockCode" name="stock_ST_StockCode" />
            <field column="ST_Name" name="stock_ST_Name" />
            <field column="ST_ItemDetail" name="stock_ST_ItemDetail" />

        </entity>
        <entity name="auction" query="select iauctionid,rad_number,vsku,auction_code from auction limit 100">
            <field column="iauctionid" name="auction_iauctionid" />
            <field column="rad_number" name="auction_rad_number" />
            <field column="vsku" name="auction_vsku" />
            <field column="auction_code" name="auction_auction_code" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

However, there are few things missing ?

- Whats the `id` field for the entity ? As each document should have a unique id, the configuration seems missing above.
- Also the `id` should be unqiue for the entites, else the stock and auction should overwrite each other.
- So you may want the id append as stock_ & auction_
- You can also add a static field as Stock and auction to your schema and populate them, which would help you the filter out the results when searching and hence improve the performance.

**For Assigning the Ids -**

You can use the following to create the id value - This should append the Stock_ with the ST_StockID field value.

```
<field column="id" template="Stock_#${stock.ST_StockID}" />
```

OR

Use alias in sql e.g. `SELECT 'Stock_' || ST_StockID AS ID` ..... as use -

```
<field column="id" name="id" />
```

Comment: Hi Jayendra, Thanks for the reply. The id field is there,stock_ST_StockID,auction_iauctionid. I appended stock_ and auction_ with all fields. If I go with the above data-config then the rows are fetched but no document is written. No index is created.  The last point of yours I did not get. There are any more change related to uniqueKey and defaultSearchField is needed in schema.xml as these two holds only first fields values.<defaultSearchField>stock_ST_ItemDetail</defaultSearchField>
 <uniqueKey>stock_ST_StockID</uniqueKey>

Comment: Id field should be a single field for both the stock and auction entity. So you would need to assign stock_ST_StockID and auction_iauctionid to the id field. Also, this id field should be unique, so that same stock id and auction id do not overwrite each other. The uniqueKey should be id.

Comment: Do I have to create a field in the db or in the schema and how to assign stock id and auction id to this id field.

Comment: No need to create a field. I added a sample example.

Comment: within the answer itself at the bottom. Section - For Assigning the Ids

Comment: Thanks, But it was giving the same error. Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.

Comment: <response>
−
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
</lst>
−
<lst name="initArgs">
−
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">full-import</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
−
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">2</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">200</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2011-11-16 15:33:23</str>

Comment: <str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str>
<str name="Committed">2011-11-16 15:33:23</str>
<str name="Optimized">2011-11-16 15:33:23</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Failed">200</str>
<str name="Time taken ">0:0:0.140</str>
</lst>
−
<str name="WARNING">
This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.
</str>
</response> Please combine the output. 0 document added/updated

Comment: There should be some error on the solr side/jetty/tomcat. back end. Can you check for the stack trace.

Comment: You want me to check the log???
[16/11/2011:10:12:07 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0 
[16/11/2011:10:12:20 +0000] "GET /solr/dataimport?command=full-import HTTP/1.1" 200 466 
[16/11/2011:10:12:21 +0000] "GET /solr/dataimport?command=full-import HTTP/1.1" 200 970 
[16/11/2011:10:12:24 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 
[16/11/2011:10:12:25 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Comment: 16/11/2011:10:12:07 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0 [16/11/2011:10:12:20 +0000] "GET /solr/dataimport?command=full-import HTTP/1.1" 200 466 [16/11/2011:10:12:21 +0000] "GET /solr/dataimport?command=full-import HTTP/1.1" 200 970 [16/11/2011:10:12:24 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 [16/11/2011:10:12:25 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Comment: Thanks Jayendra, for your time and help. I am still clueless about the issue that is occurring.

Comment: does the indexing show any errors in any logs ??? without which we cant debug the issue

Comment: Noo Error anywhere in the log. :(

Comment: not sure then as <str name="Total Documents Failed">200</str> .. says failed .. so there should be some error.

Comment: Actually the solr in not created document for the indexes, so this error is comming

Comment: try to run the dataimport with debug, you would know the queries fired, data retrived, and other information. May help.

Comment: Debug mode is not showing anything new. Same page is getting printed

Comment: Hi Jayendra, If I am running the schema.xml for only one table alternately then also index in being created. But when I combine for both tables no index in being created