# Create index on two unrelated table in Solr-2

Tags: solr, indexing

I need to create index from two tables that are not related. But when I try to do so I get the response that record fetched is equal to both tables records but no index in created. 
Please help

Comment: More information please. "I get the response..." -> who gives you that response? Are you using DIH? If so, what's the DIH config?

Comment: Hi Mauricio, Thanks for the reply. I full question can be found at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147964/create-index-on-two-unrelated-table-in-solr

Comment: and the response was got when I run full import command. document added/modified 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating 1 index from 2 unrelated tables sound very strange. Why can't you create 2 indexes?
In case you don't have other choice create unique id filed in schema (look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey). Check also in DB logs what queries are actually run.